# JQuery infinite scroll using image

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, using, infinite

Im stuck with this problem.i have set infinite content in a page and i should view only minimum content in it.i have kept arrow down image on bottom and i should hide the other contents in it and when i click the arrow down  i need to view the remaining contents using pixels

Comment: am also not clear with the question..

Comment: please help me to understand your prob..

Comment: i create one jsp page with one arrow down image. This page contain lot of contents. That arrow down image was set fixed in bottom. When i click on that image,the page should scroll down by minimum content(Ex:60px should only scroll vertically). Above contents should be hide and next minimum content have to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/11a00a4b/

```
var minimumScroll = 50;

function scrollDown() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); //current y position on the page
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: y + minimumScroll
    }, 600);
}

$('#down').click(function () {
    scrollDown()
})
```